# Why does TS complain about inferring types from object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type function so that I am able to infer the correct keys:

```js
type GroupedObject<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends `${infer Group}-${infer Rest}` ? Group : never]: {
    [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends `${K}-${infer Rest}` ? Key : never]: T[Key]
  }
}

export function groupObjectByPattern<T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T): GroupedObject<T> {
  const groupedObject: GroupedObject<T> = {} as GroupedObject<T>

  for (const key in obj) {
    const [group] = key.split('-')

    if (!groupedObject[group]) {
      groupedObject[group] = {} as Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, `${string}-${string}`>>
    }

    groupedObject[group][key] = obj[key]
  }

  return groupedObject
}
```

By doing so, I should be able to achieve correct inference. e.g:

```js
const inputObject = {
  "color-background-primary": "#ffffff",
  "color-background-secondary": "#f3f4f4",
  "color-background-tertiary": "#e4e7e7",
  "color-background-interactive": "#0b968f",
  "color-background-hover": "#026661",
  "color-background-active": "#2079c3",
  "font-primary": "foo",
  "space-xs": "xs",
};

const groupedObject = groupObjectByPattern(inputObject);
groupedObject.color; // { "color-background-primary": string; "color-background-secondary": string; "color-background-tertiary": string; "color-background-interactive": string; "color-background-hover": string; "color-background-active": string; }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
> Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
> Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
> Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.

Properties can have a key type of `PropertyKey`, which is defined as `string | number | symbol` in typescript so `keyof T` may not be a string type. So when you do `${K}-...` TypeScript complains because you can't encode a symbol into a string literal type.

I usually fix this by iterating over `keyof T & string` to only get the string properties from `T`.

Doing this seems to fix the type error:

```
type GroupedObject<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as T[K] extends `${infer Group}-${infer Rest}` ? Group : never]: {
    //          ^ added
    [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends `${K}-${infer Rest}` ? Key : never]: T[Key]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed bugging me. However, although the error has been fixed, the typing doesn't seem to infer at all.

Comment: Why you are getting a specific type error, and why your type doesn't produce your desired result are two separate questions. I encourage you to post a new question about that with the exact type you expect and what you are getting instead.